# Difference between linux and windows process

Tags: linux, windows

In linux we create a process using fork and exec ant while in windows we  use createprocess .My teacher told that linux method of creating process is more robust than windows why?

Comment: Why didn't you ask him? I would also like to hear the answer :)

Comment: He said that they researched for it and they find although it is time consuming but it is robust

Comment: The only reason I can think is that CreateProcess takes 10 parameters, whereas fork and exec total 2 parameters. It is easier to make a mistake. BTW how do you research such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork & exec are direct calls to the kernel whereas createprocess goes through window api to access kernel.

There might be more various reasons but this is what I have on top of my mind :)